# Mapping problem with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, hibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate and i am having trouble with specifying the location of the mapping file in hibernate.cfg.xml file.

I have created an Event object in org.hibernate.tutorial.chapter1.domain.Event.java package with its corresponding Event.hbm.xml file in the same location.

I am trying to specify the location in the hibernate.cfg.xml mapping tag but I am getting an InvalidMappingException ().

I have added to the post: the exception, the mapping from the mapping file and the project file structure.

any advice would be great.

> 484 [main] ERROR
>   org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger -
>   Error parsing XML (1) : cvc-elt.1:
>   Cannot find the declaration of element
>   'hibernate-mapping'. 495 [main] ERROR
>   org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger -
>   Error parsing XML (2) : cvc-elt.1:
>   Cannot find the declaration of element
>   'hibernate-mapping'. Initial
>   SessionFactory creation
>   failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException:
>   Unable to read XML

```
<!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
<mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/chapter1/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/>
```

[image: see below the project structure]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you have a DOCTYPE in your Event.hbm.xml at the top of the XML content [such as](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-mapping):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="org.hibernate.tutorial.domain">
[...]
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: the answer is still helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my XML file was missing :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

after inserting this to the beginning of the XML file everything turned out great.
Thanks!